# In Tritium, how do I add an attribute with no value assigned to it?

Tags: jquery-mobile, moovweb, tritium

I have a normal  tag:

```html
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html"> ... </a>
```

I need it to look like this:

```html
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

Why? jQuery Mobile feature: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html

The expected way below does not add the attribute, probably because Tritium ignores empty attributes.

```
attribute("data-prefetch")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Question!

The best way to do this, is to set the value of the variable to the NAME of the variable.

I would do it like this:

```
$variable_name = "data-prefetch"
$("./a") {
  attribute($variable_name, $variable_name)
}
```

This is an HTML5 convention and should work for the purposes you illustrated!

Answer (score 1):

Tritium currently has a short circuit that converts attribute assignments like the following declaration:

```
attribute("data-prefetch", "")
```

Into the equivalent of removing the attribute.

I strongly recommend you file this issue with Moovweb's help desk so that they add support for adding attributes with no values.